How can programmatically check if Excel spreadsheet is out of sync (and needs refreshing)?
I have an Excel spreadsheet which is hosted in SharePoint from which I view data. There are times in which the spreadsheet gets out of sync with the online version and as such needs to be reloaded. However it's often not noticeable that it needs to be reloaded which hinders my work and is annoying. Often even the alert only appears when you click into Excel.
Is there any way to check if the spreadsheet is out of sync? Is there a way to code something from which you can be alerted?
Edit:
The spreadsheet is used to view live data which I use to conduct my work and as such the live information is essential. I ideally wouldn't want it going a couple minutes updating at the longest.

Please add details to the question to describe why a scheduled refresh can't fix this.

@dougp maybe it could. Ca you programatically do that? If its manual that wouldn't be a solution as I would have to refresh it too many times that it would hinder my workflow.

It's one spreadsheet, right?  So you would manually configure the refresh schedule once.

a couple minutes?  You can set a limited number of daily refreshes.  Possible settings are on the 30 minute mark.  So it seems a scheduled refresh won't work for you.

You tagged this with powerbi not powerbi-desktop.  So, I'm assuming the concern is about using the online service, not the desktop app.

I think if you properly connected to the spreadsheet (Get data | web | URL to Excel file) then the connection is already live.  I suspect the data gets loaded when you open the report.  So if you are keeping the report open all day and hoping for it to refresh as new data is added to the spreadsheet, it's not going to work for you.  I think you'll need to click the refresh button in the report viewer before using the report to make decisions.

I believe i may have mistakenly tagged it then I didn't realize there were two tags, this is in relation to the desktop app

Did you try searching for this?  A web search for "power bi continuous refresh" leads me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh  Isn't that what you need?

Sorry to clarify again I am not actually using power bi atm, I was merely tagged to see if people would comment on it being a potential solution

What is Power BI ATM?  I'm not familiar with that product.
